# Quick Map Pointer Equality in Go

Tags: dictionary, go

I have a hot code path (100k runs) that optionally needs to fill a map with some values.

I am trying to optimize it and one of the things that can help would be lazy memory initializtion.
my current code is

```
mystruct struct {
   mymap
}

for i range 10000 {
    mystruct = {}
    mystruct.mymap = map[string]string
    if variable_exists {
        mystruct.mymap[variable] = blah
    }
}
```

I then later use this variable in a ton of range statements so it has to be initialized.

but the vast majority of the time the map just lays empty so it would be nice if i did not need to initialize a map just to leave it empty.
so my hope would be something like

```
mystruct struct {
   mymap
}
default_map = make(map[string]string)

for i range 10000 {
    mystruct = {}
    mystruct.mymap = default_map
    if variable_exists {
        if mystruct.mymap == default_map {
          mystruct.mymap = make(map[string]string)
        }
        mystruct.mymap[variable] = blah
    }
}
```

but that does not work.
I found deepequal but that would be wayyyyyy too slow.
most languages allow checks to see if they are pointed at the same object so how do I do that in go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the map field with `nil`. Compare the field to `nil` before adding a value to the map:

```
for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
    var m mystruct
    if variable_exists {
        if m.mymap == nil {
            m.mymap = make(map[string]string)
        }
        m.mymap[variable] = blah
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't nil freak out when used in a range statement?

This is code that is potentially used by others in a context where nil would not be an expected end result.